# PHP Display most recent images from folders

Tags: php

I would like to show most recent images from 6 folders. 
Images are named like this: 20150126.jpg, 20150127.jpg
It works, but shows all images from 1st directory than from 2nd directory etc.
How to mix it and show the newest images?

```
$directory = "*/";
$pictures = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");
$no_pictures = count($pictures)-1;  
$limit = $no_pictures-8;           
for( $i = $no_pictures; $i >= $limit; $i--){  
echo "<img width='300px' src=\"".$pictures[$i]."\" />\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Since it looks like your images names are simply a timestamp, you can sort them out from highest number to the lowest. I'm not a ninja in php, but some suggest to use natsort function()?

Comment: While I think my answer is correct, please post your $pictures array here (do print_r($pictures))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by soring your `$pictures` array. If you want the most recent to be at the top, you will want to sort in reverse, or output in reserve.

Look at `sort()`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

EDIT: In accordance with your output, I would suggest the following algorithm (although there are multiple ways to do it):

1. Get the list of directories only from the parent dir. You can use glob() with the `GLOB_ONLYDIR` option.
2. Loop through the dirs you get from 1, and get the file names for each directory (without additional path info). Merge the files into a new array with the file name first. It will have some kind of formatted string (you can go fancy with JSON or just use some simple delimiter like a colon). For example, the new array will have the entries: 20150126.jpg:ciazowe, 20150127.jpg:event, etc.
3. Sort this array.
4. Output "backwards" like you did, only with the correct path info.

Comment: But it sort. My folders looks like: folder1, folder2, folder3  and it shows:  folder3 images, folder2 images, folder1 images

Comment: Actually just post your $pictures array here please.

Comment: Array ( [0] => ciazowe/20150126.jpg [1] => ciazowe/20150127.jpg [2] => dzieci/20150126.jpg [3] => dzieci/20150127.jpg [4] => event/20150126.jpg [5] => event/20150127.jpg [6] => komercyjne/20150126.jpg [7] => komercyjne/20150127.jpg [8] => okladki/ciazowe-okladka.jpg [9] => okladki/dzieci-okladka.jpg [10] => okladki/event-okladka.jpg [11] => okladki/komercyjne-okladka.jpg [12] => okladki/portrety-okladka.jpg [13] => okladki/slub-okladka.jpg [14] => portrety/20150126.jpg [15] => portrety/20150127.jpg [16] => slub/20150126.jpg [17] => slub/20150127.jpg )

Comment: i think the problem is, that only folder names are sorting. It should be only filenames

Answer (score 0):

You should look at sort like suggested and also $arr = array_slice($arr, 0, 6);  To get your required 6.